# Timer using setInterval to announce time remaining

Tags: javascript, node.js, timer, discord, discord.js

I'm a rookie with JS but I'm trying to learn by doing! I've downloaded a free GitHub project (https://github.com/MrWall112/advanced-discord-bot-easy-install) and I'm trying to customize the timer.

So far I've added a `setInterval` event so that every 30 seconds the bot announces '30 seconds passed!' 3 times. (typically, it will run for 30s, 1m, 1m30s and 2m, as it's for a private battle server, to time individual rounds).

Using `setInterval`, the bot announces 30 seconds remaining 3 times, even if the timer has elapsed (`.timer 60s`, bot still announces 30 seconds remaining AFTER timeout)

**My question is: is there a way that I can tweak/change `setInterval` so that the bot can announce:**

```
msg.channel.send(msg.author.toString() + ` 60 SECONDS REMAINING! `)
msg.channel.send(msg.author.toString() + ` 30 SECONDS REMAINING! `)
msg.channel.send(msg.author.toString() + ` 10 SECONDS REMAINING! `)
```

So, instead of announcing 30 seconds passing 3 times, the time remaining is announced at a specific seconds?

Heres my current JS code:

```
var ms = require('ms')

exports.run = (bot, msg, params) => {

  let Timer = params[0];

  if(!params[0]){
    return msg.channel.send(":x: " + "| Please Enter a time period followed by \"s or m or h\"");
  }

  if(params[0] <= 0){
    return msg.channel.send(":x: " + "| Please Enter a time period followed by \"s or m or h\"");
  }

  msg.channel.send(":white_check_mark: " + "| Timer Started for: " + `${ms(ms(Timer), {long: true})}`)


  var i = 0;
  var a = setInterval(function() {
    if (i === 3) {
      clearInterval(a);
    }
    else {
      msg.channel.send(msg.author.toString() + ` 30 seconds passed! `)
      i++;
    }
  }
  , 30 * 1000);


  setTimeout(function(){
    msg.channel.send(msg.author.toString() + ` The Timer Has FINISHED!, it lasted: ${ms(ms(Timer), {long: true})}`)

  }, ms(Timer));
};
```

Comment: change this line `msg.channel.send(msg.author.toString() + ' 30 seconds passed! ')` to `msg.channel.send(msg.author.toString() + ' ' + (30*(i+1)) + ' seconds passed! ')`